# AngularJS: How to inject service into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I’m failing on injecting a service into a directive – it works with my controller though. According to the doc, it should be pretty straight forward.

**Service:**

```
priceGraphServices = angular.module('priceGraphServices', ['ngResource'])

priceGraphServices.factory "myService", [
    "$resource"
    ($resource) ->
        return $resource("phones/priceDev.json", {},
            get:
                method: "GET"
                isArray: true
        )
]
```

**Controller:**

```
drawGraph.controller "MyCtrl", [ "myService", "$scope", (myService, $scope) ->

    #Get RESTful data
    myService.get {}, ((data) -> 

        # If success: Data is here
        rawData = data

        # Convert date and set draw options for graph
        i = 0
        while i < rawData.length
            j = 0
            while j < rawData[i].data.length
                # Convert date
                tmp = new Date(rawData[i].data[j][0])
                rawData[i].data[j][0] = tmp

                # Set draw options
                rawData[i].opts = 
                customBars: true,
                labelsSeparateLines: "true",
                hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false,
                legend: "always",
                showRangeSelector: true,
                xAxisLabelWidth: 80,
                ++j
            ++i

            $scope.graphs = rawData

            return
        ), (data) -> #failure
            #error handling goes here
]
```

I think the code in the controller should rather be in the directive, but I don’t manage to get this right. My attempt:

**Directive:**

```
.directive "graph", [“myService”, (graph, myService) ->
    restrict: "E"
    scope: 
        data: "="       
        opts: "=?"
        id: "="

    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        scope.graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)

        myService.get {}, ((data) -> 
            # Controller Code
]
```

But that doesn’t work: No errors in the console, but an empty partial. Can anyone tell me why?

## Update:

My current directive:

```
.directive "graph", ["myService", (myService) ->
    restrict: "E"
    scope:
        data: "="
        opts: "=?" # '?' means optional
        id: "="

    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        scope.graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)

        # Get RESTful data
        myService.get {}, ((data) -> 

            # If success: Data is here
            rawData = data

            # Convert date and set draw options for graph
            i = 0
            while i < rawData.length
                j = 0
                while j < rawData[i].data.length
                    # Convert date
                    tmp = new Date(rawData[i].data[j][0])
                    rawData[i].data[j][0] = tmp

                    # Set draw options
                    rawData[i].opts = 
                    customBars: true,
                    labelsSeparateLines: "true",
                    hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false,
                    legend: "always",
                    showRangeSelector: true,
                    xAxisLabelWidth: 80,
                    ++j
                ++i

                $scope.graphs = rawData

                return
            ), (data) -> #failure


                #error handling goes here
```

## Update 2 (Compiled code):

App.js

```
var App;
App = angular.module('app', ['test']);
```

Directives.js

```
var test;
test = angular.module("test", []);

test.directive("graph", [
  "myService", function(myService) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        data: "=",
        opts: "=?",
        id: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts);
        return myService.get({}, (function(data) {
          var i, j, rawData, tmp;
          rawData = data;
          i = 0;
          while (i < rawData.length) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < rawData[i].data.length) {
              tmp = new Date(rawData[i].data[j][0]);
              rawData[i].data[j][0] = tmp;
              rawData[i].opts = {
                customBars: true,
                labelsSeparateLines: "true",
                hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false,
                legend: "always",
                showRangeSelector: true,
                xAxisLabelWidth: 80
              };
              ++j;
            }
            ++i;
            $scope.graphs = rawData;
            return;
          }
        }), function(data) {});
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Does the `graph` parameter of the directive hold a reference to the service? Directives take only their dependencies as arguments, and `graph` is no dependency of your directive.

Comment: Thank you @frececroka, I've updated the code with according to your hint (if I got it right it's the same as baba's answer below). Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.rubyinside.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/dhh12.png

Comment: http://jordankasper.com/js-testing/images/meme-refactor.jpg

Comment: Sound like an issue with the compilation. Can we see the compiled output of the coffee script for this directive?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tC8JN.png

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/07/075ce92e99ebe938916211887be4afacfe6c8f532a50036109be4ab48530c8f4.jpg

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/60/60ee82214c9a8b9442dff4944c852485729ea922ea8f819725719fe213de4d2d.jpg

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/500x/43477129.jpg

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian I updated my code above with the compiled js. It feels like I don't get the wiring up of the modules right, but not sure (read the tutorial and doc again, it looks right to me). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: looks like `$scope.graphs = rawData;` should be `scope...` (i would stick with $scope for consistency) and you will most likely need to use `scope.$apply()` as $resource is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
.directive "graph", [“myService”, (myService) ->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @baba, I've updated my code above with your suggestion, unfortunately I still doesn't work. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: yo, have you tried doing it in pure js? What kind of js does it produce?

Comment: I updated my code above with the compiled js. It feels like I don't get the wiring up of the modules right, but not sure (read the tutorial and doc again, it looks right to me). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```
app = angular.module('app', [])

app.directive "graph", ["myService", (myService) ->
    restrict: "E"
    scope:
        data: "="
        opts: "=?" # '?' means optional
        id: "="

    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        scope.graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)

        # Get RESTful data
        myService.get {}, ((data) -> 

            # If success: Data is here
            rawData = data

            # Convert date and set draw options for graph
            i = 0
            while i < rawData.length
                j = 0
                while j < rawData[i].data.length
                    # Convert date
                    tmp = new Date(rawData[i].data[j][0])
                    rawData[i].data[j][0] = tmp

                    # Set draw options
                    rawData[i].opts = 
                        customBars: true
                        labelsSeparateLines: "true"
                        hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false
                        legend: "always"
                        showRangeSelector: true
                        xAxisLabelWidth: 80
                    ++j
                ++i

            $scope.graphs = rawData
            return

            ), (data) -> #failure

                #error handling goes here
]
```

Try this plugin: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScript%20%26%20Coffeescript%20Build%20Systems

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ilan Frumer for the effort and the link to the plugin. I fear I got the initialization of the module for the directive wrong, because it still doesn't work. It's just "angular.module 'app', []" above the directive, right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @user3255061 I don't see how your modules are connected.

Comment: I again read the modules tutorial (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) - did I connect them wrong? I updated the code above. Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate that.